# Jquery Ajax Form Submission not refreshing/reloading

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

so my goal is to add a person to my form without the page reloading.
But when I press submit to add a person, the information is sent through, but I don't see it append to my dropdown, the only way I can see it, is to refresh/reload the page, which I don't want to do.

index.php

```
<form method="post" id="personForm">
                First Name:     <input type="text" id="firstName"     name="firstName"> <br><br>
                Last Name:      <input type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName">   <br><br>
                Favorite Food:  <input type="text" id="favoriteFood" name="favoriteFood">   <br><br>
                <button type="submit" id="addPersonSubmit" name="addPersonSubmit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
                </form>
```

When the user fills out the form and presses submit, my javascript will handle it. "drive.js"

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
$('#personForm').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    addPerson();
});


function addPerson()
{
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "api/people", // api/people
    data: $("#personForm").serialize(),
     success: function(data,status,xhr) 
    {
        console.log(data);
        console.log(status);
        console.log(xhr);
        console.log($("#personForm").serialize());
        console.log("You have added a person");
        populatePeople();
        displayData();
    },
     error: function(data,status,xhr) 
    {
        console.log(data);
        console.log(status);
        console.log(xhr);
        console.log($("#personForm").serialize());
        console.log("error");
    }
});
```

}

Now as the javascript fires, it sends that information to my api.php 
api.php will check for requests and then call the insertPerson()function.

```
//insert a Person //api/people
function insertPerson()
{
global $connection;

$firstNameEnter = $_POST["firstName"];
$lastNameEnter = $_POST["lastName"];
$foodEnter = $_POST["favoriteFood"];

if(!empty($firstNameEnter) && !empty($lastNameEnter) && !empty($foodEnter))
{
    // Insert values into table
    $sql = "INSERT INTO People (firstname, lastname, food) 
    VALUES ('$firstNameEnter', '$lastNameEnter', '$foodEnter')";

    // Check if insert is good
    if(mysqli_query($connection, $sql))
    {
        echo "You have added a friend: " . " First Name: ". $firstNameEnter . " Last Name: ". $lastNameEnter . " Food: " . $foodEnter;
    }
}

else 
{
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $connection->error;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't using serializeArray() do you better in this situation?

Comment: where is the code that appends the person to the dropdown? It seems to me that populatePeople() would probably do that, from the name of it, but how does it know which person to add? Can you show us the rest of your code? (just js will do, the php appears to be working since after page reload the result is as expected)

Comment: I don't know how it would be. I only want to serialize a form. Can you provide an example? 

Also, I know they're some sytnax errors of ( }); because I deleted some of them because I was frustrated.

Comment: https://github.com/PaulChu756/statesvisited/blob/master/public/drive.js

(edit)So I append my new person by calling the populatePeople() again, but also here is my github, I didn't want to post my code in the comments to make it so long.